# Please clarify @ and pointer and without them when adding object in delphi?

Tags: delphi

Please let me understand the following code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Alist: TStringlist;
  i: integer;
begin
  Alist:=TStringlist.Create;
  Alist.Add('form1=form1');
  Alist.AddObject('form1',form1); //case 1
  Alist.AddObject('Pointer(form1)',Pointer(form1)); //case 2
  Alist.AddObject('Pointer(@form1)',Pointer(@form1)); // case 3
  Alist.AddObject('@form1',@form1); //case 4

  for i:=0 to Pred(Alist.Count) do // case getname
    Memo1.lines.add(Alist.Names[i]+' = '+ 
      inttostr(integer(Alist.Objects[i])));
  for i:=0 to Pred(Alist.Count) do // case getvalue
    Memo1.lines.add(Alist.ValueFromIndex[i]+' = '+
      inttostr(integer(Alist.Objects[i]))); 
end;
```

Case getname will generate:

```
form1 = 0
 = 13967624
 = 13967624
 = 4537296
 = 4537296
```

Case getvalue will generate

```
form1 = 0
orm1 = 13967624
ointer(form1) = 13967624
ointer(@form1) = 4537296
form1 = 4537296
```

Questions:

1. Please clarify difference between case 1,2,3 and 4. especially case 2 and 3
2. Can I always use any of them in all situations, ie, treat them always the same when adding object? if no, when should I use them differently?
3. I know case getname, but why case getvalue can still have Names though I did not add like add('form1=form1') and the returned is short of the first character?

This is reproduced from Delphi 7.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Number 3 is probably because you are adding strings that are not in the `a=b` format, yet you are requesting the `b` part. The implementation probably gets the item from the corresponding index and then drops the first character assuming it to be `=`. Morale: only use Name/Value stuff when you are actually putting Name/Value stuff in the list.

Comment: Classes and objects are implicitly pointers (already). And `@` operator references its operand so the result is pointer to pointer in your case (of type ^TForm1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the question #3 - `Names` and `Values` make sense only if the strings contain `NameValueSeparator` (`=` by default). Your strings (except the first) does not contain `=`. On Delphi XE your code outputs

```
form1 = 0
 = 32552528
 = 32552528
 = 5214864
 = 5214864
form1 = 0
 = 32552528
 = 32552528
 = 5214864
 = 5214864
```

which looks better.

Comment: Thanks so much. You helped me previously. And explained '=' in stringlist. So in D7, it can not be used that way.

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2 are identical. 3 and 4 are identical.

An object reference already is a pointer, hence the equivalence of 1 and 2. The typecast in 2 is gratuitous.

For 3 and 4, @anything is a pointer and again, the typecast is gratuitous.

1 and 2 save the object reference in the list. 3 and 4 save a pointer to a variable holding the object reference.

The Names and Values properties are for working with items of the form 'name = value'. I don't think that is appropriate to the other part of your question.

Comment: Very clear explanation for question 1. But I can not split the accepted answer into 2. David,You replace with new logo image.

Comment: @Warren Fine. Of course that's one of the reasons why it can be better to ask two questions in two separate questions. You are more likely to get better and more focused answers that way too, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

1. A class is already a pointer, so typecasting it to a pointer does nothing. @ is address-of operator in Pascal, the value is also a pointer, so again typecasting it to a pointer does nothing.

   form1 or pointer(form1) is the pointer to the form1 instance.
   @form1 or pointer(@form1) is the pointer to pointer to the form1 instance.
2. Depends on what you want to store in the list
3. Don't know about this one, have never used it before

Comment: Thanks so much for immediate reply

Comment: To be be precise, form1 is a reference to an object and is not a class. The class is the type and the object is the instance of the class.